# Cause: java.sql.SQLException: connection is closed

Tags: java, mysql, druid

1. db : Mydql
2. connection pool ： Druid
3. jdk7
4. mybatis

   ```
   org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
   ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: connection is closed
   ### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis1/hotel/StopRoomRecordMapper.xml]
   ### The error may involve StopRoomRecordMapper.getByModel
   ### The error occurred while executing a query
   ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: connection is closed
   ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: connection is closed
           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:90)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
           at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)
           at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:364)
           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.selectOne(Unknown Source)
           at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:159)
           at com.leyizhu.dao.DaoSupport.findForObject(DaoSupport.java:155)
           at com.leyizhu.dao.hotel.impl.StopRoomRecordDaoImpl.getByRoomTypeIdAndTradeDate(StopRoomRecordDaoImpl.java:96)
           at com.leyizhu.dao.hotel.impl.StopRoomRecordDaoImpl.save(StopRoomRecordDaoImpl.java:34)
           at com.leyizhu.service.hotel.impl.StopRoomRecordService.save(StopRoomRecordService.java:31)
           at com.leyizhu.service.hotel.impl.StopRoomRecordService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5ef83be9.invoke(<generated>)
           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
           at com.leyizhu.service.hotel.impl.StopRoomRecordService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b431adda.save(<generated>)
           at com.leyizhu.task.timer.client.RecordStopRoom.execute(RecordStopRoom.java:54)
           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
           at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: connection is closed
           at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.checkState(DruidPooledConnection.java:1050)
           at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.getAutoCommit(DruidPooledConnection.java:722)
           at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:81)
           at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:66)
           at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:315)
           at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.prepareStatement(ReuseExecutor.java:78)
           at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:58)
   ```

**mycode**:

```
@Override
public void save(StopRoomRecord model) throws Exception {
    StopRoomRecord stopRoomRecord = getByRoomTypeIdAndTradeDate(model.getRoomtypeid(), model.getTradedate());
    if (stopRoomRecord != null) {
        //存在则更新数据
        model.setId(stopRoomRecord.getId());
        update(model);
    } else {
        //否则新增
        model.setId(UuidUtil.get32UUID());
        model.setCreatetime(new Date());
        dao.save("StopRoomRecordMapper.save", model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration your DataSource bean (connection pool). I use SingleConnectionDataSource for my single-thread application. Try DriverManagerDataSource for tests.

Launch your application with --trace key. It may be useful.